# Trying to ignore null textboxes in Winforms to filter sql search query

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

Currently I'm trying keeping a persistent where clause and then appending additional filter by appending if each textbox is present or not. The problem is this is giving me a good command to work with but I still receive an error when trying to use that command. If there is any simplification or guidance it would be much appreciated!

```
if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(make) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(model)) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(color)) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(min)) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(max)) && (string.IsNullOrEmpty(miles)))
            {
                SqlCommand updateDataGridViewCmd = new SqlCommand("select m.make, m.model, car.price, color.color, car.mileage, carlot.lotid, car.pic from car join makemodel as m ON m.mmid = car.mmid join color ON  car.colorid = color.colorid join carlot ON  carlot.carid = car.carid; ", sqlCon);

                dt.Load(updateDataGridViewCmd.ExecuteReader());
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }
            else
            {
                StringBuilder sqlCommandText = new StringBuilder();
                sqlCommandText.Append("select m.make, m.model, car.price, color.color, car.mileage, carlot.lotid, car.pic from car join makemodel as m ON m.mmid = car.mmid join color ON  car.colorid = color.colorid join carlot ON  carlot.carid = car.carid where");
                string CommandText = sqlCommandText.ToString();

                SqlCommand updateDataGridViewCmd = new SqlCommand(CommandText, sqlCon);
                updateDataGridViewCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@make", make);
                updateDataGridViewCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@model", model);
                updateDataGridViewCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@min", min);
                updateDataGridViewCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@max", max);
                updateDataGridViewCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mileage", miles);
                updateDataGridViewCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@color", color);



                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(make))
                {
                    sqlCommandText.Append(" m.make = @make");
                    CommandText = sqlCommandText.ToString();
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(model))
                {
                    sqlCommandText.Append(" OR m.model = @model");
                    CommandText = sqlCommandText.ToString();
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(min))
                {
                    sqlCommandText.Append(" car.price between @min");
                    CommandText = sqlCommandText.ToString();
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(max))
                    {
                        sqlCommandText.Append(" AND @max");
                        CommandText = sqlCommandText.ToString();

                    }
                    else 
                    {
                        sqlCommandText.Append(",");
                        CommandText = sqlCommandText.ToString();
                    }
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(color))
                {
                    sqlCommandText.Append(" color.color = @color,");
                    CommandText = sqlCommandText.ToString();
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(miles))
                {
                    sqlCommandText.Append(" car.price <= @mileage");
                    CommandText = sqlCommandText.ToString();
                }
                sqlCommandText.Append(";");
                CommandText = sqlCommandText.ToString();
                dt.Load(updateDataGridViewCmd.ExecuteReader());
                dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;
            }

                
        }
    }
```

ERROR:
[image]

Comment: Is it possible to use any ORM here? It would help a lot when dealing with dynamic queries

Comment: What error? Please add some more information otherwise is just a guess game

Comment: Probably because you are not chaining the conditions using one of `and, or`

Comment: Lots of syntax errors with the SQL you're generating. Take a look at it in the debugger

Comment: What's the command?

Comment: Why you repeat CommandText = sqlCommandText.ToString(); every time, while you need it just at the end?

Comment: @AndreaRossini I changed that to just one ToString() at the end

Comment: @TomasChabada the screenshot has an appended or

Comment: @Steve error added

Comment: \@make and \@model inside the query are syntactically incorrect. Apparently you intend to pass some dynamic parameters that are not passed and, instead, copied into the query by their name.

Comment: Can you test directly running the query without the where clause?

Comment: @LajosArpad yes without it works, but when build the string with where clauses it doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

You may see an error because you are not joining your condition strings either with `and` or `or`. 
If ORM is not an option here (which may be practical when composiong queries) you can end the base query with `where 1=1` and then chain the other conditions with `and x=...` or `or x=...` 
Also you can set `CommandText = sqlCommandText.ToString();` only once, after all filters have been applied

Comment: ive tested for make and model which gives me                                                                      `select m.make, m.model, car.price, color.color, car.mileage, carlot.lotid, car.pic from car join makemodel as m ON m.mmid = car.mmid join color ON  car.colorid = color.colorid join carlot ON  carlot.carid = car.carid where m.make = @make OR m.model = @model;`                                                                          which is stored in commandtext is this not a valid query?

Comment: I re-edited to show the text in commandtext

Comment: `WHERE 1=1` is unnecessary. Capture the conditions in a `List<string>` then combine them e.g. `string.Join(" OR ", myConditions)`

Comment: @Eric But they are not all `and` or `or`. It is mix od them. Joining them all using string. Join will result in values separated with same separator

Comment: `string.Join("  ", myConditions)` where `myConditions` includes the `and`/`or` term. Mixing and with or without parenthesis to specify an order of operations isn't useful in a general sense.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this being a pseudo-code. I wrote it from my head in this editor. Basically, instead of dealing with endless conditions, create an object that will group your conditions and then group the output of instances of these objects. It should build a perfect filter for you.

```cs
public class WhereToken
{

    private List<SqlParameter> _localColl;
    // privates declared here
    privat bool _between;

    public WhereToken (string col, object[] values, SqlDbType t, SqlParameterCollection paramColl)
    {
       // assign privates here
    }

    public WhereToken (string col, object value1, object value2, SqlDbType t, SqlParameterCollection paramColl)
    {
        // assign privates here
        _between = true;
        _values = new object[]{value1, value2};
    }

    public string Write()
    {
        if (values.Length = 0)
            return null;
        _localColl = new List<SqlParameter>();

        var b = new StringBuilder();
        b.Append("(");
            for (int i = 0; l < _values.Length; i++)
            {
                var pName = string.Concat("@", col, i); 
                var p = new SqlParameter(pName, values[i], _sqlType);
                b.Append(_col);

                if (_between)
                    b.Append(" BETWEEN ");
                else
                    b.Append("=");

                b.Append(pName);
                if (i < values.Length - 1)
                {
                    if (_between)
                        b.Append(" AND ");
                    else
                       b.Append(" OR ");
                }
            }

        b.Append(")");

        foreach(var pp in _localColl)
            _paramColl.Parameters.Add(pp);

        return b.ToString();

    }

}

// In code

var tokens = new List<WhereToken>();
var wt1 = new WhereToken("make", new string[]{txt.Make.Text}, SqlDbType.NVarchar, sqlCommand.ParameterCollection);
tokens.Add(w1);

// in real life, you need to check if both values present, etc
var wt2 = new WhereToken("year", Convert.ToInt32(txt.YearMin.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txt.YearMax.Text), SqlDbType.Int, sqlCommand.ParameterCollection);
tokens.Add(w2);

// more items here . . . . 

var builder = new StringBuilder(yourMainSQLSelect); 
builder.Append(" WHERE 1=1"); // 1=1 what if the tokens don't generate
for (int i = 0; i < tokens.Length; i++)
{
    string token = tokens[i].Write();
    if (token == null) continue;

    builder.Append(" AND ");
    builder.Append(token);
}

sqlCommand.CommandText = builder.ToString();
```

This code ^^ should build you something like

`... where 1=1 and make=@make0 and (year BETWEEN @year0 AND @year1)`

Of course, you can improve built-in logic on how to parse and output from `WhereToken`. But this is the concept for you - parse small tokens then join them. Don't try build logic for all input fields

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me, that you want to expand your WHERE with predicates if some input string are null or empty.

Let's ignore empty string, so I won't have to write: `is null or empty string`

```
SELECT ... FROM TABLECUSTOMERS WHERE <predicate1> OR <predicate2> OR ...
```

The predicates that you add depend on which input strings are null. It seems to me that most of the times, if the input string is null, you want to omit the predicate. Something like this:

```
if (inputStringName != null)
{
   strBuilder.Append("OR CustomerName = @Name")
}
```

This is the same as:

OR (@Name != null AND @Name == CustomerName)

And if you want to use AND instead of OR:

```
AND (@Name == null OR @Name == CustomerName)
```

So my advice would be: make one SQL command, that contains all possible variables, and change the command such that the predicate also testing whether the parameter equals null

```
SELECT ... FROM car
JOIN ...
WHERE ( NOT @Make = NULL AND @Make = m.Make)
   OR ( NOT @Model = NULL AND @Model = m.Model)
   OR ( NOT @Mileage = NULL AND @Mileage > car.Mileage)
```

So just before you use the parameter you check whether the parameter is null or not. Depending on whether you want to append with AND or OR use something like:

- OR (NOT @Value = NULL AND @Value = car.MyValue)
- AND (@Value = NULL OR @Value = car.MyValue)

My SQL is a bit rusty, I use entity framework all the time, so I am a bit uncertain about the `NOT =`, maybe this should be `!=`, and maybe there should be more parentheses, but I guess you get the gist.

To prevent to have to check for Empty strings: make empty strings null, before you `AddWithValue`